# Precision of floating point operations

Tags: c++

Floating point operations are typically approximations to the corresponding arithmetic operations,  because in many cases the precise arithmetic result cannot be represented by the internal number format.  But what happens if I have a program where all numbers can actually be represented  exactly by IEEE 754 single precision?  Consider for example this:

```
float a = 7;
float b = a / 32.0;
float c = a + b;
float d = c - a;
assert( d == b );
```

Is it safe to assume that within this and similar cases, the result of the numerical calculation is identical to the exact arithmetic result?  I think this sort of code would work on every actual machine. Is this correct?

**Edit**  This question is not about what the standard says, but rather about the real world.  I'm well aware that *in theory* one could create a conforming engine where this would fail.  I don't care, but rather I wonder if this works on *existing* machines.

Answer (score 2):

No as the c++ standard does not require floating point values to be stored in the IEEE 754 format.

Comment: But what about implementations that do use IEEE 754, or at least most of it? That's a rather important case, as it's common and has many implications beyond what's guaranteed by the C++ standard.

Comment: @user1937198 Thanks.  Are there any implementations that are not compatible with IEEE 754 single precision?

Comment: in the case of IEEE 754 I can't find anywhere in the working draft (I don't have access to the standard at the moment) that allows the implementation to round internally so it looks like it should. But beware optimisers and [pentiums](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_Bug) if your going to really on this.

Comment: @pentadecagon: GCC on many architectures is not fully IEEE 754 conformant unless you tell it to, and that requires software implementations.

Comment: @Kerrek As far as I know this only applies to corner cases like Infinity or denormals or things like this.  Are you aware of any case where the result of a numerical operation would be different from the exact arithmetic results, as long as all numbers stay in the range specified by IEEE 754 single precision?

Comment: @pentadecagon: For one single operation, no, I don't know. GCC has other popular optimizations that violate IEEE 754 when applied to a larger number of operations, though I suppose those are marked as "unsafe"...

Answer (score 0):

"Real" machines are quite careful in implementing the standard exactly (just remember the [Pentium division bug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pentium_FDIV_bug)). But be careful to check, the i386 line of machines did use some extra bits in its registers, which were cut off when asigning to/from memory, so computations done only in registers gave different results than if some intermediate results where spilled to memory.

Also check out David Goldberg's [What every computer scientist should know about floating point arithmetic](https://ece.uwaterloo.ca/~dwharder/NumericalAnalysis/02Numerics/Double/paper.pdf).

In any case, it doesn't make any sense to "round" (or otherwise mangle) a number that can be represented exactly.

Comment: Sorry, I don't get it.  Does this mean "yes" or "no"?

Comment: The bit about extra bits in fpu regiters applies to all x86 processor scalar fpus. Its just that if the compiler knows its the code will run on a processor with SSE it uses the vector registers instead.